# How to reuse JQuery events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, browser

I have a bunch of divs with following structure:

```
<div id="content">
  <span class="highlight">Hello1<span> 
  <span class="highlight">Hello2<span> 
  <span class="highlight">Hello1<span> 
  <span class="highlight">Hello2<span> 
  <span class="highlight">Hello1<span> 
  <span class="highlight">Hello2<span> 
</div>
```

I am adding mouse 3 events on `highlight`  in small function and on some action on div i'm changing div content some other span tags so earlier mouse events useless still persist in memory which increases browser memory exponentially when span tags around 1000 it increases by MB.

Is there any way so that i can reuse earlier mouse event of span tags to new div content span tags?

Comment: No one can tell unless you add your code here.

Comment: `$('#content').on('eventname', '.highlight'...)`

Comment: If I understand the question right, you keep a log of all the events you have so far, kind of like a revision marking, and you want to apply them on every new span added, right?

Comment: Assuming I got the question right, my answer would be to increase your storage capacity. Either serialize events to string and keep them on the dom, use the local storage API or cookie to increase storage even more. ( cookie not recommended, but supported better than local storate API ).

Answer (score 2):

you need to delegate your events from a parent container `$(document.body)` for example

see http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document.body).on('events list','selector',function(e) {
       //do stuff
       })
                .on('event list2','selector2',function(e) {
       //do stuff
       })
        //etc...
```

it won't consume any more memory no matter the number objects bound to those events